# Creating a triangle out of numbers with nested while loops

Tags: ruby, while-loop, nested-loops

The teacher for my Ruby class has a program that asks the user for a number and then counts up or down from the number into a triangle shape. If the user enters the number 5, it prints:

```
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

This is the teacher's code:

```
print "Enter a starting number: "
size = gets.to_i
line = 0
while line < size
  count = 1
  while count <= size - line
    print count
    count += 1
  end
  puts
  line += 1
end
```

For the class, I need to do the same thing as above along the lines of my teacher's code, but start from 1 and count up to the number that the user entered. For example, if the user enters 5, I need to print:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

I'm not looking for someone to do my assignment for me, I just need some help and I'm hoping someone can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: If you found an answer particularly useful be sure to select and accept an answer by clicking the relevant grey tick so it turns green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* you have to use `while` loops based on your example, try:

```
print "Enter a starting number: "
size = gets.to_i
line = 1

while line <= size
    count = 1
    while count <= line
        print count
        count += 1
    end
    puts
    line += 1
end
```

*Else* try:

```
print "Enter n: "
n = gets.to_i
puts

(1..n).each do |i|
    (1..i).each {|j| print j }
    puts
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First one

```
size = 5
size.times do |n|
  puts (1..(size-n)).to_a.join('')
end
```

Second one

```
size = 5
size.times do |n|
  puts (1..(n+1)).to_a.join('')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow a similar format to your teachers code, the following works

```
print "Enter a starting number: "
size = gets.to_i
line = size - 1
while line >= 0
    count = 1
    while count <= size - line
        print count
        count += 1
    end
    puts
    line -= 1
end
```